# Что помогает в осваивание LINUX?

Tags: debian, linux

Где находить учения 
например как устанавливать различные программы?

Какая сборка оптимальная для перехода с win7/8
вопросов уйма

и главный вопрос как не соскочить обратно на win?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

%)

Я бы вначале порекомендовал бы научиться пользоваться гуглом, иначе успех в осваивании очень мал.

1. через диспетчер приложений (или как он там), через консоль, через запуск по двойному клику на пакет
2. Ubuntu / Mint
3. ЧО?? ))) А для чего вам Linux?